# Converting ipywidgets.widgets.widget_output.Output to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipywidgets

I have created a function that allows a user to make selections from a checklist and return the selected values. The issue is that the returned checklist is of type ipywidgets.widgets.widget_output.Output and I cannot find a way to extract the values inside the result.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

def create_checklist():
    data = {"label1": "data1", "label2": "data2"}

    names = []
    checkbox_objects = []
    for key in data:
        checkbox_objects.append(widgets.Checkbox(value=False, description=key))
        names.append(key)

    arg_dict = {names[i]: checkbox for i, checkbox in enumerate(checkbox_objects)}

    ui = widgets.VBox(children=checkbox_objects)

    selected_data = []
    def select_data(**kwargs):
        selected_data.clear()

        for key in kwargs:
            if kwargs[key] is True:
                selected_data.append(key)

        print(selected_data)

    out = widgets.interactive_output(select_data, arg_dict)
    display(ui)
    return out

checklist = create_checklist()

print("Displays just fine: ")
display(checklist)

print("But cannot print or use in any way. Print result: ")
print(checklist)

print(f"\nChecklist type: {type(checklist)}")
```

After selecting 'label2' result:

```
Displays just fine: 
['label2']

But cannot print or use in any way. Print result: 
Output()

Checklist type: <class 'ipywidgets.widgets.widget_output.Output'>
```

Under certain contexts you can also get it to print(checklist) and result in:

```
Output(outputs=({'output_type': 'stream', 'text': "['label2']\n", 'name': 'stdout'},))
```

I have obviously tried list(checklist), checklist.text, checklist['text'], to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your `selected_data` list up to the global scope:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

selected_data = []   # in global scope rather than local scope to function

def create_checklist():
    data = {"label1": "data1", "label2": "data2"}

    names = []
    checkbox_objects = []
    for key in data:
        checkbox_objects.append(widgets.Checkbox(value=False, description=key))
        names.append(key)

    arg_dict = {names[i]: checkbox for i, checkbox in enumerate(checkbox_objects)}

    ui = widgets.VBox(children=checkbox_objects)


    def select_data(**kwargs):
        selected_data.clear()

        for key in kwargs:
            if kwargs[key] is True:
                selected_data.append(key)

        print(selected_data)

    out = widgets.interactive_output(select_data, arg_dict)
    display(ui)
    return out

checklist = create_checklist()
```

Then you should be able to call `selected_data` anywhere in following cells and get the currently selected values.

[image]

Comment: This works! I don't think I understand WHY it works, but I'm happy it does! Thank you!

Comment: It's all to do with function scopes, and what data is accessible from them. It's a tricky but essential topic: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scope-of-variables-python

Answer (score 0):

Actually, upon further investigation, the issue isn't around local v global variables, it is simply returning the correct local variable! Simply return 'selected_data' instead of out and it returns a list of selections!

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

def create_checklist():
    data = {"label1": "data1", "label2": "data2"}

    names = []
    checkbox_objects = []
    for key in data:
        checkbox_objects.append(widgets.Checkbox(value=False, description=key))
        names.append(key)

    arg_dict = {names[i]: checkbox for i, checkbox in enumerate(checkbox_objects)}

    ui = widgets.VBox(children=checkbox_objects)

    selected_data = []
    def select_data(**kwargs):
        selected_data.clear()

        for key in kwargs:
            if kwargs[key] is True:
                selected_data.append(key)

        print(selected_data)

    out = widgets.interactive_output(select_data, arg_dict)
    display(ui)
    return selected_data

checklist = create_checklist()

print("Print checklist: ")
display(checklist)

print(f"\nChecklist type is list: {type(checklist)}")
```